# Adding a table row that does not change any column width

Tags: css, html

I have a table that is rendered quite well (using Bootstrap 4) without specifying column widths.

I want to add a footer that contains an input field for each column. Adding the footer changes the width of the columns, and really makes the table too wide. How can I add a table cell and instruct the browser not to use it when calculating the column width?

You can see an example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zmbq/aq9Laaew/149476/). Simply comment out the `<tfoot>` and see how the table is rendered without the inputs. I want to add the inputs without changing the column size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no CSS-only way to do this.

Javascript can do it, of course, so on the off chance that you won't consider that cheating, here is the solution.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var theTable = document.querySelector('.container .col-12 .table-condensed');
  var firstRow = theTable.querySelector('thead tr').cells;
  var footElements = theTable.querySelectorAll('tfoot th *');

  // First, we set the widths of all the contents of the tfoot to 0 so it won't take up space
  for (var i = 0; i < footElements.length; ++i)
    footElements[i].style.width = '0';

  // Then we fix the widths of the columns to the widths they have now
  for (var i = 0; i < firstRow.length; ++i)
    firstRow[i].style.width = '' + firstRow[i].offsetWidth + 'px';
  theTable.style.tableLayout = 'fixed';

  // And finally we change the widths of the tfoot contents back to what they were
  for (var i = 0; i < footElements.length; ++i)
    footElements[i].style.width = '';
};
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            <th>Col 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Lengthy cell with lots of text</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="text"></th>
            <th><input type="text"></th>
            <th><input type="text"></th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the inputs in col 2 and col 3 are too wide for the columns, so they overflow out of their cells (out of the table even), but the solution to that I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I considered doing something like that, but ended up doing something even simpler - I fixed the column widths (with percentages) myself.

Comment: OK. I'll leave this up though, in case someone finds this and needs a dynamic solution.

Comment: I'm actually marking this as the correct answer, as this is the only answer the provides a solution to the problem.

Comment: By the way, don't we need to let the browser refresh the table once we change the width at first? I would expect having to call `setTimeout` before setting the fixed width.

Comment: @zmbq It wasn't necessary to unaccept G-Cyr's answer, since it does provide an answer given the restrictions in the question; mine only provides an alternative for people who are looking for a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @zmbq No, including a delay isn't needed; the table resizes immediately upon changing the width properties.

Answer (score 2):

bootsrap 4 uses `table-sm` instead `table-condensed`. That might not be enough, you can declare the table-layout in the CSS and add a max-width to inputs:

```
table {table-layout:fixed;}
input {max-width:90%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c06tomp9/

---

You may also take the input of the flow so they do not come into size calculation bothering column's width.

```
table {border:solid;}
tfoot tr th {position:relative;height:3.4em;/* an height needs to be set to hold the inputs unseen */}
input {position:absolute;max-width:90%;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c06tomp9/1/

Comment: Thanks for the `table-sm`, it does make things a bit nicer, but doesn't solve my issue. I don't want to have a fixed table, the browser sets the column widths properly, based on their content - I want to keep this behavior. I just want to tell the browser to ignore the footer row when deciding how wide each column should be.

Comment: without table-layout set to fixed, the table will expand its width to fit to the content it holds unfortunately :(

Comment: @zmbq the trick could be to use absolute to avoid inputs to mess with the column's width calculation . https://jsfiddle.net/c06tomp9/1/  Mind to set an height to the cells and position: relative to size absolute children. you may also need to reset text-align to left .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table-layout: fixed;` on the table so the width of the columns won't change when adding rows, but then all columns have the same width by default, and if you to change it you need to set the width explicitly.

Comment: Indeed. However, i do not want to lose the automatic table layout, I just want the browser to ignore the footer when calculating the layout.